# Android Toast Messages are not shown using Fuel Framework

Tags: android, kotlin, httpresponse, android-toast

I am using [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) to send and receive requests from an API.

However, I am not able to show Toast Messages or AlertDialogs, if the request was not successful.

Sample Code:

```
private fun validatePassword(): Boolean {
    var minPasswordLength = 0
    val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_password_register).text.toString()
    val password_repeat: String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_password_repeat_register).text.toString()


    "/auth/password.json".httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
        //do something with response
        request.header(mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/json"))
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "password_Curl", request.cUrlString())

        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
                val data = response.data.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
                Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Response_Password_Fail", data)

                val jelement = JsonParser().parse(data)
                val jobject = jelement.asJsonObject

                Toast.makeText(this, jobject.get("Error").asString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                val data = response.data.toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
                Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "Response_Passwd_Succes", data)

                val jelement = JsonParser().parse(data)
                val jobject = jelement.asJsonObject

                minPasswordLength = jobject.get("minimal_length").asInt
            }
        }
    }
    return password.length >= minPasswordLength && password.equals(password_repeat)
}
```

I have tried to run the makeText command on the UIThread using:

```
runOnUiThread{Toast.makeText(this, jobject.get("Error").asString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
```

This did not work either.

I do however get to the code while debugging:
[image: dubug_screenshot]

Thanks for the help! Cheers.

**UPDATE:** 
While debugging I noticed that minPasswordLength stays 0 even though **"minimal_length"** from the API has the value 8. So maybe it is a Threading problem?

Comment: Is the toast method called, do you check it from debug

Comment: yes if I debug the code I get to the Toast line,  however, It is not displayed

Comment: Are you sure that the `Toast` is not displayed? Maybe it's empty. 

Have you tried hardcoding a message there, like `Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`?

From which library does the `JsonParser` come?

Comment: @WojciechJanuszek I have tried it, yes didn't work; It's not empty tho the screenshot above is in debug mode hence the remarks in green were real-time values. The JsonParser is from GSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.15.0` instead of `implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.15.0'` in the `dependencies` (`build.gradle` file).

The JVM implementation of the library doesn't automatically invoke the handlers in the UI thread.

---

This works for me even in the JVM implementation:
`runOnUiThread { Toast.makeText(this, "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }`

I think that it didn't work for you because the JSON doesn't contain the `"Error"` but `"details"` field.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the dependency to com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.15.0 worked for me